# How to resolve/remove (presumably) erroneous optional update in WUAUSERV?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

[image: Screenshot]

I had deleted some obsolete network driver entries (or I had thought they were obsolete/duplicates anyway) via `RAPR.exe`, but afterwards this started to show up under optional updates.  I have an i7 coffee lake on a Maximus X Hero Wifi AC board, so I'm fairly sure this is not a relevant/correct driver, especially after reading [this](https://community.intel.com/t5/Processors/why-there-is-200-series-chipset-driver-in-windows-10-pro-for/td-p/701402).

There were actually more entries than shown in the above screenshot initially, but after learning of the `-overall` run switch/argument from the referenced thread, I went ahead and reinstalled the most current chipset version offered through the ROG Forums with the argument ([here](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?117609-DRIVERS-Intel-Chipset-MEI-SATA-(1xx-2xx-3xx-4xx)/page4)), after which the update screen changed to the above.  Can anyone advise how to resolve this so it doesn't remain an eyesore at the very least?  Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to post my system specs!
[image: Specs]

Comment: Use the Microsoft tool to block the driver update, however, suspect part of the problem is the fact your on an Insider Preview build.

Comment: ** pci\ven_8086&dev_1901** is the device identification for the applicable device.  If your machine has that device then despite the name of the update it is applicable to your machine

Comment: @Ramhound No, I do not have this device, which based upon the HardwareID is identified as [Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=ebef2d98-42bd-47ad-89f1-6e3414c6756d).  PCI Lookup also enumerates as the same device.  So either the two devices share a common driver, or for whatever reason the HardwareID was changed/overwritten unintentionally?  Can the latter even occur?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I thought I had posted up my system specs, I guess I didn't!  I'll edit the post shortly.

Comment: @Ramhound I just reread your first comment, can you elaborate on what tool you're referring to?  Or did you mean to just simply pause the system updates?

Comment: “Can the latter even occur?” - No